# WordPress script to run function "store first letter of keyword" goes through but does nothing

Tags: wordpress, alphabetical, letter

we are hoping you could help point us in the right direction here.
We have a script running on our site that when a post is saved or updated in WordPress, the first letter of the keyword in the field "keyword" is placed in the custom taxonomy "alphabetical_letter". This works perfectly thanks to a script provided by the advanced custom fields plugin support.

However we want to mass update all of our posts instead of going through them one by one. We wrote the following code which goes through, however does not provide any result. We must me missing something but after a few days of trial and error we were hoping you could help us out here.

```
function kia_run_once(){

    if ( false === get_transient( 'kia_run_once' ) ) {
 //vars
        $keyword = get_field('keyword');
        $taxonomy = 'alphabetical_letter';
        $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );

//action
        foreach( $posts as $p ) :
        //set term as first letter of keyword, lower case
          $first_letter = strtoupper(substr($keyword, 0, 1));

        wp_set_post_terms( $p->ID, $first_letter, $taxonomy );

        endforeach;

        set_transient( 'kia_run_once', 'true' );

    }

}
add_action('init','kia_run_once');
```

Comment: Is the function get_field() from Advanced Custom Fields plugin? Probably should be used *inside* the foreach?

Comment: yes, get_field is from the plugin. So I end up with something like this ?
        foreach( $posts as $p ) :
        //set term as first letter of keyword, lower case
    $keyword = get_field('keyword');
          $first_letter = strtoupper(substr($keyword, 0, 1));

If I do so and run the script, I get a memory exhausted message...

Answer (score 0):

How many posts have you to pass through? Probably a mysql update should be better.

Anyway you can try first eanbling error loggin (see [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)) and writing out some debug lines using 'error_log()' or 'print_r()', getting the return from 'wp_set_post_terms()' and stopping execution after few cycles; I mean something like this:

```
$cnt = 0; 
foreach( $posts as $p ):
    $keyword = get_field('keyword');
    error_log('keyword is: '.$keyword);
    //set term as first letter of keyword, lower case
    $first_letter = strtoupper(substr($keyword, 0, 1));
    $ret = wp_set_post_terms( $p->ID, $first_letter, $taxonomy );
    error_log('result is: '.$ret);
    $cnt = $cnt + 1;
    if ($cnt>10) break;
endforeach;
```